# Digital Ocean droplet's console how to start services?

Tags: digital-ocean, spectre, droplet

Digital Ocean rebooted all droplets 3 days ago but when they came back, my website was down.
Problem seems to arise because all related services (httpd, mysqld, iptables etc) are inactive and have to activate them again.
First of all did anybody else had the same issue and
secondly how can i run `systemctl start/stop/restart <service>` through droplet's console (sshd not running so droplet's console it's the only way to get into my system)?
Seems that whenever i perform this action console kicks me off, as it is in emergency mode.
I don't know if it's useful info but system is fedora 21.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo systemctl enable service.service
```

to have a service start automatically when your droplet boots.

Comment: Thank you Oliver. Unfortunately this won't work. I enabled sshd.service, rebooted the droplet and when i entered the console, service was inactive again.

Comment: What was the output when you ran the command? Also, I think you should try `systemctl enable ssh.service` (e.g. not sshd)

Comment: It just kicks me out of the service and asks me again for password. Anyway this was a problem that had to do with the entire filesystem that occured immediately after a reboot made by the admins. Nobody knows why it occured. After that they just announced in their blog some problems in FRA1 (where i'm hosted), that are trying to fix. In personal level, support team didn't give me any other tip. They just mounted a recover iso image to gain access via ssh and sftp to my files...